# For what values does $\sin(x+h) = \cos x$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

For what and how many values of h such that $0 \leq h \leq 100$ are the graphs $a(x) = \sin(x+h)$ and $b(x) = \cos x$  identical?

I am not sure where to start. Hints only please.

Comment: Well, there is a pretty well-know identity that tells you how far to shift $\sin$ to get $\cos$. If you need a hint, have Wolfram Alpha draw both of the graphs and try to figure out how to shif one to get the other.

Comment: You need one method/identity to find one value for $h$ (there are a couple ways as indicated by Johanna and Prahlad).  And then use another property of these trig functions to find all the rest.

Comment: **Hint::** Physically speaking, both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ describe [waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave#Sinusoidal_waves) which have a [phase difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)#Phase_difference) of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}\ \text{rad}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sin(h+x)=\cos(x)\implies \sin(h)\cos(x)+\cos(h)\sin(x)=\cos x$$
Now, for what value of h does $\cos(h)=0, \sin(h)=1?$

Here's a unit circle for reference:
[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0CAcQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FUnit_circle&ei=ykirVJvgBJOwogTdmoD4Dg&bvm=bv.83134100,d.cGU&psig=AFQjCNH-1f4eFcQ9LgVxIcbIjUFXcAIz-g&ust=1420597817799483]
Also note that $\sin(2\pi+x) , \cos(2\pi+x)=\sin(x) , \cos(x)$
Therefore, when you find $h$, add multiples of $2\pi$ to obtain all the possible values of $h$.

Comment: @MathNoob: Would it be: $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $\frac{9\pi}{2}$, $\frac{13\pi}{2}$, $\frac{17\pi}{2}$, $\frac{21\pi}{2}$, etc., But how far would I go? I'm not sure how to convert from radians with $\pi$ in it to see if h is in the bounds $0 \leq h \leq 100$.

Comment: All you have to use is $\pi\approx 3.14\implies \frac{21\pi}{2}\approx 32.5$. Another way is to find which value of x will be your last value:
$$\frac\pi 2+2\pi x=100$$
$$x=\frac{100+\frac \pi 2}{2\pi}$$
Then you would only need to Find $x<$ solution of the given equation.

Comment: @MathNoob: I see now, that was what I originally thought. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MathyPerson Therefore if you calculate correctly, you should get that the greatest value is $\frac{61\pi}{2}$. If you did not get this value feel free to ask me for more help.

Comment: @MathNoob: Yep, I got the greatest value of $\frac{61\pi}{2}$ as well. I also upvoted and accepted/check-marked your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try the formula
$$
\sin(x+h) = \sin(x)\cos(h) + \cos(x)\sin(h)
$$
and plug in suitable values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

both functions are $2\pi$ periodic. so if you know how many times $a$ and $b$ are identical for $h$ in one period $0 \le x 2\pi,$ then you can figure out how many periods there are in $100$ multiply by the number of coincidences in one period.

now you are back to figuring out the number of times $\sin(x+h)$ and $\cos(x)$ are identical for $0 \le h \le 2\pi.$ how many translation to the left of the $y = y=\sin(x)$ match the graph $y = \cos(x)$

hint: (i) draw the  graphs $y = y=\sin(x)$ and $y = \cos(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 2\pi$
      (ii) keeping the $x$ and $y$ axes fixed translate the $\sin x$ graph left and see where it coincides with that of the fixes $\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(x+h)=\cos x=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\iff$$

$$\iff\begin{cases}x+h=\frac\pi2-x\iff x=\frac\pi4-\frac h2\\{}\\
x+h=\pi-\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\iff h=\frac\pi2\end{cases}\;\;\;+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: The pattern would go as: π/2, 5π/2, 9π/2, 13π/2, 17π/2, 21π/2, etc., But how far would I go? I'm not sure how to convert from radians with π in it to see if h is in the bounds 0≤h≤100

Comment: $$0\le h=\frac\pi2+2k\pi\le100\iff-\frac\pi2\le2k\pi\le100-\frac\pi2\iff$$$$\iff-\frac14\le k\le\frac{50}\pi-\frac14$$ and this gives you the bounds for $\;k\;$. In the first case I think you have to take all the possible values of $\;h\;$ .

Comment: Hint:  $\frac{5 \pi}{2} \approx \frac{5 \times 3.14159 } {2}$